# Pandas_profiling error (I tried ydata_=profiling too)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pydantic, pandas-profiling

I am trying to make a profile report on a data i imported to pandas.
but it give me a pydantic error

```
import pandas_profiling 
profile_report = df.profile_report()
```

i also tried methods like

```
from ydata_profiling import ProfileReport
```

but I get this error:

PydanticImportError: `BaseSettings` has been moved to the `pydantic-settings` package. See https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.4/migration/#basesettings-has-moved-to-pydantic-settings for more details. For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.4/u/import-error
Traceback:
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\streamlit\runtime\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 541, in *run_script
exec(code, module.**dict**)
File "C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Desktop\AutoML\app.py", line 5, in 
import pandas_profiling
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas_profiling_*init**.py", line 8, in 
from ydata_profiling.compare_reports import compare
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ydata_profiling_*init*_.py", line 7, in 
from ydata_profiling.compare_reports import compare
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ydata_profiling\compare_reports.py", line 9, in 
from ydata_profiling.config import Correlation, Settings
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ydata_profiling\config.py", line 7, in 
from pydantic import BaseModel, BaseSettings, Field, PrivateAttr
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pydantic_*init*_.py", line 218, in **getattr**
return _getattr_migration(attr_name)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pydantic_migration.py", line 294, in wrapper
raise PydanticImportError(

Answer (score 0):

It can be a simple versioning problem, have you checked requirements at https://github.com/ydataai/ydata-profiling/blob/develop/requirements.txt? For pydantic you need pydantic>=1.8.1, <2 for ydata-profling 4.6.0.